# noob homework question window dimensions in java

Tags: java, window, dimensions

I am a high school student taking cs106a at Stanford via video.

For my current assignment I have to add GObjects and position them relative to the size of the window.

I  am currently trying to get the width of the window using the command

```
int width = getWidth();
```

however width = 0

One thing that could be causing this:
     this is one of the first programs I have written using multiple classes.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you didnt say what problem you were having. and dont say "i cant get width". provide an error or something

Comment: If you posted code and how/where it failed, you would be more likely to receive guidance.

Comment: I reposted this with more code and details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible cause - you may be calling `getWidth()` before the window (I'm assuming `JFrame`) has been realized (aka had `setVisible(true)` or `pack()` called on it).  `getWidth()` will return 0 before it is realized.

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

In the absence of example code from you, I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you're checking width in the constructor of your class, or at some other time either before the underlying OS window has been created, or after it has been destroyed.

If you try to get window attributes during these times, you'll probably get zero or some other nonsense result.